# How can you best answer when a Scholarship proposal asks for your objectives?

Tags: funding, application, computer-science

I come from a developing country and I got admitted to a UK university in MSC, Computer Science. As I am not financially strong, I am also applying for a fully funded scholarship. There is an online form I need to submit for the consideration of this scholarship.

There are some questions that I can't answer them in the way the needs to be answered and convenes the scholarship organization. One of them is:

> What will be your objectives during the award?

If I answer this question it would be simple like the following:

> My main objective during the period is to get more and more knowledge and to learn new technologies that will give boost to my career.

I'm guessing this answer isn't viewed positively from by a scholarship committee.

*What content do scholarship committees expect to see in the "Objectives" section of an application?*

Comment: What is "your career" going to be? What do you want to do for the world that makes you worth investing in? That's the answer they're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

"During the award" sounds a bit strange to me; I guess it means during the period covered by the scholarship. First, I'd be sure to answer the question with specifics, not generalities. Something like "During the award period, my objectives are: 1) to complete the first year with an A average grade, 2) to master programming skills in Java (or whatever) such that I can independently program a controller for quad-power drone aircraft, and 3) ... etc.

Comment: Gary, yes they were asking about the time period covered by the scholarship.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to answer the question. Please review it. If you find something missing or inappropriate let me know.

"In my Masters program my goal is to expand my mental horizons, detailed understanding of latest tools and technologies adopted by engineering, with the time. I also want to learn technical, managerial as well as behavioral aspects of the field to work in higher positions. I strongly feel that master’s program will inculcate a strong quality assurance and testing component in my knowledge, so as to raise the level of excellence in my work. I came to know that an academic experience is must-to-have component for growth in global field of Computer Science, as well as to make a mark in professional career. From use of sophisticated tools to advanced theories, MS teaches me all that I need to know to enhance my academic experience and qualification."

Comment: Wouldn't impress me. Sure, this stuff can be fun, and can be profitable... but why should we support _you_, rather than the guy who wants to go into smart prosthetics or whatever?